# Alternative Desktop Environment for OL9 OL8

Tags: desktop-environment, oracle-linux

The Oracle Linux distros 8 and 9 have some of the worst Linux Desktop Environments Ive ever come across and I would like to try something different. Having a hard time finding documentation or guides on this.

On fedora Mate and Cinnamon are very good Desktops. Is it possible to install them into OL9? I'll try anything at this point.  Also Terminal windows without borders is an awful idea that everyone is doing.

Comment: I use full-screen terminal windows without borders. But I am an old guy... everything is possible, it is more hard to say, what it the best for you. In your place, I would try ubuntu. Regarding your question, I would suggest to remove statements from the question - you are asking for something, not here to say negative from linux things.